# Appending class to parent div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an accordion which I am trying to append a class to but am struggling to do so. Appending .faq-active to the 'a' and 'content' div works fine, however I am trying to append an active class to the parent div of 'accordion-item' which doesn't appear to work. It's worth noting that I am trying to append to the parent class so if there is a more efficient way to do so I am open to it.

**HTML:**

```js
      

const accordion_item = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".faq-accordion a");

function accordion(){
    this.classList.toggle('accordion-active');
}

function toggleAccordion(){
    this.classList.toggle('faq-active');
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('faq-active');
}

accordion_item.forEach(accordion => accordion.addEventListener('click', accordion));
items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

```html
<div class="faq-accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <a>FAQ Title</a>
        <div class="content">
            FAQ Description
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <a>FAQ Title</a>
        <div class="content">
            FAQ Description
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Using `parentElement`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that you are passing an element into the `addEventListener` parameter.
`accordion_item.forEach(accordion => accordion.addEventListener('click', accordion));`

The variable `accordion` is being set to the element in the `forEach` loop, but you want `accordion` to be a function. The solution is very simple, just change the name of the function, or the variable name in the `forEach`.

**Working Code:**

```js
const accordion_item = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".faq-accordion a");

function accordion() {
  this.classList.toggle('accordion-active');
}

function toggleAccordion() {
  this.classList.toggle('faq-active');
  this.parentElement.classList.toggle('faq-active');
}

accordion_item.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', accordion));
items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

```css
body {
  user-select: none;
}

.accordion-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 3px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #000;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.faq-active {
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion-active {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <a>FAQ Title</a>
    <div class="content">
      FAQ Description
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <a>FAQ Title</a>
    <div class="content">
      FAQ Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/SnowLord/z6aLpgn9/

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const faq_accordion = document.querySelector(".faq-accordion");
    const accordion_item = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item");
    const items = document.querySelectorAll(".faq-accordion a");

    faq_accordion.addEventListener('click', faqAccordion);

    function faqAccordion(){
      this.classList.toggle('accordion-active');
    }

    function accordion(){
        this.classList.toggle('accordion-active');
    }

    function toggleAccordion(){
        this.classList.toggle('faq-active');
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('faq-active');
    }

    accordion_item.forEach(accordion => accordion.addEventListener('click', accordion));
    items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

```html
<div class="faq-accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <a>FAQ Title</a>
        <div class="content">
            FAQ Description
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <a>FAQ Title</a>
        <div class="content">
            FAQ Description
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go with a simple toggler, then you can determine what to do.
As it is, if you click and it is not active, it activates it, otherwise it inactivates the other and makes the clicked one active.  I did this in two ways one on the element and one on it's parent so you could see how it might work.  I added a border to the class for illustration. Try clicks on the FAQ Description or the FAQ Title

```js
const accordion_item = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item > .content");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".faq-accordion a");

function doToggle(classT, el) {
  let cActive = document.querySelectorAll("." + classT);
  let elActive = cActive[0];
  let isSame = el == elActive;
  //console.log('doToggle',classT, aActive, "el:", el, "isSame:", isSame);
  if (!!cActive.length && !isSame) {
    elActive.classList.toggle(classT, false);
  }
  if (!el.length) {
    el.classList.toggle(classT);
  }
}

function itemToggle(event) {
  let classT = 'accordion-active';
  event.stopPropagation();
  let closestElement = this.closest('.accordion-item');
  doToggle(classT, closestElement);
}

function toggleFaq(event) {
  let classT = 'faq-active';
  event.stopPropagation();
  doToggle(classT, this);
}

accordion_item.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', itemToggle));
items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleFaq));
```

```css
.accordion-active {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}

.faq-active {
  border: solid blue 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-accordion ">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <a>FAQ Title</a>
    <div class="content">
      FAQ Description
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <a>FAQ Title</a>
    <div class="content">
      FAQ Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```